# Graph Theory : Job Assignment Problem

Tags: graph-theory

Problem is to assign 5 jobs to five people. How many non-planar graphs can be drawn such that no vertex is isolated?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please show your work on the problem and we will be gald to give hints.

Comment: I tried it using bipartite graph, i.e assign to the set of jobs an object from the set of persons but I do not know how to find the non-planar graphs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *mothers* of all non-planar graphs are $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ as you know. The second of those is the one you want to avoid. That restricts how you can partition jobs into groups, since you cannot have 3 and 3 from both sides.

Can you think of what the valid partitions now would be? Can you take it from here?

**EDIT** Some further hints. Consider the bipartite graph $G$ with $V = J \cup P$ where $J = \{j_1, \ldots, j_5\}$ and similarly $P = \{p_i\}_{i=1}^5$. If a job $j_k$ is assigned to the person $p_n$, add the edge $e = \{j_k, p_n\}$ to the edge set $E$. Clearly, $G$ is bipartite by construction.

1. Each different assignment of jobs to workers corresponds to a different edge set of $G$. How many possible assignments are there?
2. You cannot have isolated vertices, so this means at least one edge to everything on both sides - i.e. must assign every job and every worker. How many ways to do that?
3. Can you now enforce the planarity by yourself?

Comment: It would be great if you could explain a bit more.I am struggling in this topic and have exams nearby. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2047167 see the edit